# Current manipulator and active objects have no keyable attributes Error in Autodesk Maya

Tags: animation, controller, maya, locked

I am using Dana rig from Gabriel Salas. A controller named FKRoot_M cannot set a keyframe. I get the error // Warning: file: /Applications/Autodesk/maya2020/Maya.app/Contents/scripts/others/doSetKeyframeArgList.mel line 633: Current manipulator and active objects have no keyable attributes, or animation layers are present and the BaseAnimation bar is not selected or locked. //.

I need to fix it so I can make her move. I deleted any references from reference editor. What else can I do?

Comment: Did you reference the rig? If so, does it come with a base animation layer? That layer might be locked due to it being referenced. If you don't see any animation layers, then maybe the control you are trying to key is not intended to be keyed? Root control sounds like it might just be for positioning the rig in scene and might be locked for animating. I usually do something like that when I just want the animator to position the characters but not animate the root controller of the rig.

Comment: No, the specific root controller can be unlocked since it happened to work with it in the past. I am not sure why now where I referenced it, remains locked. There are no animation layers to infer a base animation layer. Now that is referenced yields the error // Error: file: /Applications/Autodesk/maya2020/Maya.app/Contents/scripts/others/PScreateLockingUI.mel line 287: setAttr: The attribute 'Dana_Rig_v1_7:Dana_Rig_v1_5:FKRoot_M.translateX' is from a referenced file, and cannot be unlocked. //

Comment: What I would do then is:
- open the maya rig (don't reference it)
- check the controller for any incoming connections (it might be connected to an empty animation curve)
- if it has incoming connections on the channels that cause issues, break the connection
- save the rig as new file
- try referencing the newly saved file and see if the problem persists.
My assumption is, that the rig file has connections but no keys in the curve.

Answer (score 0):

//Current manipulator and active objects have no keyable attributes, or animation layers are present and the BaseAnimation bar is not selected or locked.//

with J and H keys in Graph Editor is work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).